# MySQL FTP solution with decent password hashing support?

Tags: mysql, hash, ftp, bcrypt, pureftpd

We're looking for a FTP solution with native support for a decent hashing algo, (bcrypt or such). Solutions such as vsftpd, proftpd and pureftpd all support basic crypt(), md5, and password() functions. However we're wondering if there may be a better solution out there?

We're aware of Pure-ftpd having scrypt support, however we're unable to get this to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, and ended up shipping a pure-ftpd authentication module that implemented the authentication logic in Python. We were even able to integrate with our public API for single sign-on. You could use this method to use the password hashing algorithm of your choice, or to integrate with third-party authentication solutions like Facebook or Github. For more information, check out https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.Authentication-Modules